# CSS rounded corners not working on all icons

Tags: html, css

Can someone please tell me why the `border-radius:50%` property doesn't work on all icons? 
I have to write different padding settings for each, but i want to do all the same.

```css
.social a {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  speak: none;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  line-height: 0;
  width: 20px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  top: 62px;
  left: 25%;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #2f5183;
  border-radius: 50% !important;
  transition: 0.3s;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="social">
  <a href="#" class="facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
  <a href="#" class="google"><i class="fa fa-google"></i></a>
  <a href="#" class="twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
</div>
```

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/hqwg00qf/5/

Comment: your facebook icon is just smaller....it functions as it's behavior allows it.

Comment: 50% doesn't mean make it a circle just like 50% height and width of your screen isn't necessarily a square

Answer (score 3):

It works, corners are rounded.

Problem is in setting `width` for `inline` a elements, which doesn't work (you can't set width/height to inline elements). Add `display: inline-block` to links.

```
.social a {display: inline-block; ...}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hqwg00qf/19/

Answer (score 0):

Set `display: inline-block` css property to selector `.social a`
https://jsfiddle.net/hqwg00qf/31/

Answer (score 0):

just add css display:inline-block to your icons

```
.social a {
    display:inline-block;
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    line-height: 0;
    width: 20px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    top: 62px;
    left: 25%;
    font-size: 22px;
    padding: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #2f5183;
    border-radius: 50% !important;
    transition: 0.3s;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hqwg00qf/40/

Answer (score 0):

`<a></a>` tag default display type is 'inline';

So,Just add

```
.social a {
   display:inline-block;
}
```

I think it solve you problem.

Thank you.